# Json : getting the unwanted result

Tags: json

I'm using json plugin to get the response in json.
But I m getting the unwanted result:

Here is what I get:

```
{"data":"[[\"service\",\"webservices\",\"document\"],[\"validation\",\"adapters\",\"server\"]]","records":25,"recordsTotal":75}
```

originally the data var in my action class is like this:

`[["service","webservices","document"],["validation","adapters","server"]]`
but json plugin adds the backslash.

The wanted result is that:

```
{"data":[["service","webservices","document"],["validation","adapters","server"]],"records":25,"recordsTotal":75}
```

Is there a way to get the later result ?

Thanks

Comment: is the data variable that string? or is it actually an array of arrays?

Comment: I understand what you mean. You are right, I was using the wrong type for data variable.

Comment: neat, happy to help. since it solved your problem I posted it as an answer too - if you could accept that'd be awesome. happy holidays :)

Comment: happy holidays and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're representing the data as a PHP string. `"` is obviously a reserved character in JSON, so your serialization library is dutifully escaping the quote using `/`.

If you set up the PHP variable so it's an array of arrays, instead of a string representing an array of arrays, then your JSON serialization will work fine.